# How do i minimize node-webkit window to taskbar?

Tags: node-webkit

[image]

```
<div name="ControlDiv-1" id="ControlDiv-1" class="ControlDiv-1" onclick="javascript: window.close()"> </div>
```

That obviously closes that window, but How can I do the same thing and minimize the window instead of close. I looked at the documentation and I found `window.min()` but I cannot get it to work. It creates and error instead of minimizing.

Comment: Why `id="ControlDiv-1" class="ControlDiv-1"`

Comment: Does that help explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To minimize node-webkit app to task bar, AFAIK you have to do two things

```
window.hide()

window.setShowInTaskbar(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this worked for me:

```
var win = gui.Window.get();
win.setShowInTaskbar(true);
win.minimize();
```

Comment: Can you include some details of what this is doing to add context to the code? Thanks!

Comment: This minimizes the application to the taskbar just like any other Windows application. You can restore the application by clicking on its icon on taskbar.